# Magento v2.2.6: Proceed to Checkout displays a login popup even after logged in

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.2.6, popup

A **login popup** window is displayed after clicking **"Proceed to Checkout"** button from **cart** instead of redirecting to **checkout page**.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the issue please Follow all the steps.

1. Try disabling other modules one by one.(custom installed not core ones)

   you can use the command to disable magento modules in magento 2 root directory

to check the modules status: 
   `php bin/magento module:status`

and to disable: 
`php bin/magento module:disable:name_of_your_module`
   then run the all basic commands everytime after module disable or enable :

```
php bin/magento c:f; php bin/magento s:up; php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento s:s:d -f; php bin/magento i:rei
```

2. Try selecting The default magento theme.
3. Try by looking at the core code change in Magento by comparing it with fresh magento of your installed magento version with codecompare software.

Hope this will help you to debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behaviour when guest checkout is not allowed, you can check the settings in **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout**